# Why does my Rails app not see installed gems?

Tags: ruby, apache, rubygems, passenger, rvm

Running Ubuntu 10, RVM, Passenger and apache2. Trying to configure and get [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) running.

First, I set my default Ruby binary to `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby`. That's the output of `which ruby`. Output of `which gem` is `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem`. I think that side of things is set up properly.

I know Passenger is running, because I'm getting an error screen, with this error:

> **Error message:**
>
> > Missing the i18n 0.4.2 gem. Please `gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n`

**Update** The error that passenger is producing is coming from the `boot.rb` file. I went and [made a gist of the application's boot.rb file](https://gist.github.com/1030038).

When I do check to see if that gem is installed, here's the output.

`# gem list`
`# ... list truncated ...`
`# i18n (0.4.2)`
(full gist of installed gems [here](https://gist.github.com/1030040))

Really? Let's first make sure passenger.conf is going to the right Ruby installation...

> passenger.conf
>
> > `PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby`

**>:|** So now, I go onto SSH into the application directory, and what have you, `script/server` starts normally. I'm a little more than confused. Clearly the Ruby installation that Passenger is configured to has the Gem it says is missing, installed, and additionally, the application doesn't falter on a start up. Which makes me think it's a Passenger problem.

Comment: No, how do you gather that? In other news, I am figuring this out, a piece at a time. The code that is generating the error message comes from the Ruby command `rescue Gem::LoadError => load_error` which just breaks on **any** Gem load error. So now I am working backwards from the `boot.rb` file to make sure all dependencies are being met.

Comment: Why are you running `script/server` instead of `rails server`?

Comment: I'm just seeing if the app will execute, and it does.

Comment: Where do you run `rails server`?

Comment: well in rails 3 the way to run your app is `rails s` in your root folder of your app. That's the only way to deploy your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RVM with Passenger is a bit complicated, maybe this link about using [Ruby and Passenger](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/) will help.